# How to change font size through command?

Tags: java, android

I want to change font size of the text "Congratulations" of below code in last line of the code

```
byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
cmd[0] = 0x1b;
cmd[1] = 0x21;
cmd[2] |= 0x10;
mService.write(cmd);
mService.sendMessage("Congratulations!\n", "GBK");
```

Comment: You need to find the control that renders that text (e.g. TextView or EditView) and change the font size there.

Comment: actually i am sending text to BT printer..

Comment: its prints defualt size of text

Comment: You should refer to the manual of that printer instead. Printers from different manufacturer has different SDKs thus different ways to change font size.

Comment: What does "through comment" mean in the title of this question?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy as you can see after Congratulations where is "\n" its breaking the line..... can we put it inside string and work with it?

Comment: @DavidConrad sorry its commend not comment.... its been changed automatically

Comment: @Miniman No you can't. I bet changing font size requires you to send a bunch of byte commands like the first 4 lines of your code.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy can u refer me any examples... or help me with it

Comment: Assuming by "commend" you mean "command", edited.

Comment: @Miniman As I mentioned before, each printer has different implementations. You need to find your printer's SDK or manual to know what exactly you need to do to change font size. Google with the printer's brand and model number should get you started.